# In tensorflow.js, how do I compute the gradient wrt a model input?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'd like to compute the gradient of loss with respect to the input vector in TensorFlow.js.

Here's what I tried:

```
function f(img) {
  return tf.metrics.categoricalCrossentropy(model.predict(img), lbl);
  // (Typo: the order of arguments should be flipped, but it does not affect the question here)
}

var g = tf.grad(f);

g(img).print();
```

`img` is a tensor of shape [1, 784]. `lbl` is a tensor of shape [1, 10]. `model` is a vanilla MNIST DNN trained with `tf.Sequential`.

The call to `g(img)` fails with the stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
    at gradFunc (Concat_grad.js:29)
    at Object.s.gradient (engine.js:931)
    at a (tape.js:158)
    at tape.js:136
    at engine.js:1038
    at engine.js:433
    at e.t.scopedRun (engine.js:444)
    at e.t.tidy (engine.js:431)
    at e.t.gradients (engine.js:1033)
    at gradients.js:69
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `model.predict(img)` returns ?

Comment: It returns a tensor of shape [1, 10] (same as `lbl`). There's no problem with the line `tf.metrics.categoricalCrossentropy(model.predict(img), lbl)` as far as I can tell; it returns the correct tensor of shape [1].

Comment: if you change that line with`tf.metrics.categoricalCrossentropy(tf.ones([1, 10]), lbl)`, there is no error. If `model.predict` returns the correct tensor, then moving it out of the scope of `tf.grad` will solve the error

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow. I'd need `model.predict` to be in scope of `tf.grad` because I want to compute the gradient of loss wrt the input image, right? i.e. what pixels to tweak to increase the model's loss.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I executed your code by using `tf.ones([1, 10])` instead of the output of `model.predict` and it worked. So possibly that the error is coming from what is predicted by the model

Comment: Yep, well, the forward pass of `model.predict` works fine (the output shape and prediction quality look good). I'm not sure how to make `model.predict` work with `tf.grad` properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223611/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-kennysong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original code snippet is correct; there was a `tf.grad` [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4130) in 2.6.0 and 2.5.0 versions of TensorFlow.js that caused this error.

The code works as intended in 2.4.0, or in the new release 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `model.predict` outside of the scope of `f`, `tf.grad` will work.

```
function f(img) {
  return tf.metrics.categoricalCrossentropy(img, lbl);
}


var g = tf.grad(f);
const output = model.predict(img);

g(output).print();
```

There seems to be an error with sequential model that is fixed from release `2.7 +`

Comment: I mentioned this in chat, but this snippet computes ∂loss / ∂logits rather than ∂loss / ∂image. I believe `model.predict` needs to be inside `f` to compute the latter.

Comment: The error was actually due to [a bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4130) in TF.js, which was just fixed. My original code now runs fine. Thanks for the helpful discussion!